# Узнать значение первого элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
options: [
  { id: '1', text: 'Option A' },
  { id: '2', text: 'Option B' }
],
```

Добрый день, как узнать id первого элемента в массиве, то есть в данном случае должно вывести 1

Желательно без использования for если возможно

Comment: console.log(options[0].id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        options: [
            { id: '1', text: 'Option A' },
            { id: '2', text: 'Option B' }
        ],
    },
    created() {
       console.log(this.options[0].id);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```